# blank screen when running jupyterlab

Tags: python, jupyter, miniconda, jupyter-lab

I have installed jupyterlab via miniconda3 and when I am launching jupyter lab I get an empty browser, I am running it on Windows 7 with python 3.6
Actually I haven't noticed anything wrong in the log file and i don't know if it is related to the browser. I precise that I am running jupyterlab in IE
here the log :

```
(C:\Users\G30622\Desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3) C:\Users\G30622\Desktop>jupyter
lab --debug > log.txt
[D 11:22:19.787 LabApp] Searching ['C:\\Users\\G30622\\Desktop', 'C:\\Users\\G30622\\.jupyter', 'c:\\users\\g30622\\desktop\\miniconda3\\miniconda3\\etc\\jupyter', 'C:\\ProgramData\\jupyter'] for config files
[D 11:22:19.787 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 11:22:19.787 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 11:22:19.787 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\G30622\.jupyter
[D 11:22:19.787 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_config in C:\Users\G30622\Desktop
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\ProgramData\jupyter
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\etc\jupyter
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Loaded config file: c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\etc\jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.json
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\G30622\.jupyter
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Loaded config file: C:\Users\G30622\.jupyter\jupyter_notebook_config.py
[D 11:22:19.797 LabApp] Looking for jupyter_notebook_config in C:\Users\G30622\Desktop
[D 11:22:20.337 LabApp] Terminals not available (error was No module named 'fcntl')
[I 11:22:20.337 LabApp] JupyterLab alpha preview extension loaded from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 11:22:20.437 LabApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\G30622\Desktop
[I 11:22:20.437 LabApp] 0 active kernels
[I 11:22:20.437 LabApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 11:22:20.437 LabApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=7c270403de19cbae77707b25adf469d7a5ac03278e6b2adb
[I 11:22:20.437 LabApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 11:22:20.447 LabApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=7c270403de19cbae77707b25adf469d7a5ac03278e6b2adb
[D 11:22:20.457 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136539361 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:20.457 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136538893 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:20.457 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136539458 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:20.467 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136539663 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:20.597 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136538569 (::1) 0.00ms
[I 11:22:20.597 LabApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:20.607 LabApp] Using contents: services/contents
[D 11:22:20.627 LabApp] 200 GET /lab?token=2d4ed1377f35a30a252eb3794f4e3b440f1fa2c1d08a703f (::1) 30.00ms
[D 11:22:20.657 LabApp] Path main.bundle.js served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\static\main.bundle.js
[D 11:22:20.657 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/static/main.bundle.js (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:20.657 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\MathJax.js served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\MathJax.js
[D 11:22:20.657 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full,Safe&delayStartupUntil=configured (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:20.947 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js
[D 11:22:20.957 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML-full.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:20.977 LabApp] Path components\MathJax\config\Safe.js served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\static\components\MathJax\config\Safe.js
[D 11:22:20.979 LabApp] 304 GET /static/components/MathJax/config/Safe.js?rev=2.6.0 (::1) 2.50ms
[D 11:22:21.227 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.227 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.227 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.257 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.257 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.259 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.259 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.262 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.262 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.262 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.264 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.264 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.264 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:21.269 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1510136541222 (::1) 42.50ms
[D 11:22:21.272 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.274 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes?1510136541262 (::1) 2.50ms
[D 11:22:21.274 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.279 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/shortcuts-extension:plugin?1510136541255 (::1) 5.00ms
[D 11:22:21.299 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.302 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/fileeditor-extension:plugin?1510136541284 (::1) 2.50ms
[D 11:22:21.304 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.307 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/build?1510136541280 (::1) 2.50ms
[D 11:22:21.309 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.312 LabApp] 200 GET /lab/api/settings/@jupyterlab/codemirror-extension:commands?1510136541293 (::1) 2.50ms
[D 11:22:21.519 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:21.519 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136541508 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:21.572 LabApp] Path @jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css servedfrom c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\index.css
[D 11:22:21.572 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-light-extension/index.css (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:21.622 LabApp] Path @jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\variables.css served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\variables.css
[D 11:22:21.632 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-light-extension/variables.css (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:21.632 LabApp] Path @jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\urls.css served from c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\lab\themes\@jupyterlab\theme-light-extension\urls.css
[D 11:22:21.632 LabApp] 304 GET /lab/api/themes/@jupyterlab/theme-light-extension/urls.css (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:23.232 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136543205 (127.0.0.1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:23.412 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136543398 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.862 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136549452 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.862 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136549668 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.872 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136548574 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136548899 (127.0.0.1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136551246 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.882 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.892 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1510136546205 (::1) 20.00ms
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.902 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1510136545355 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:33.912 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136553204 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:33.922 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136553396 (127.0.0.1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:33.922 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136549346 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:38.602 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136558574 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:38.922 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136558912 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:39.362 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136559355 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:39.472 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136559462 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:39.692 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136559677 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:41.262 LabApp] Accepting token-authenticated connection from ::1
[D 11:22:41.272 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136561245 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:43.222 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136563205 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:43.402 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136563395 (::1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.702 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.712 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.712 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.712 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.712 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.722 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.722 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:44.722 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1510136564678 (127.0.0.1) 30.00ms
[D 11:22:48.602 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136568573 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:48.922 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136568912 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:49.362 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136569354 (127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[D 11:22:49.492 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136569472 (127.0.0.1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:49.692 LabApp] 200 GET /api/sessions?1510136569668 (::1) 10.00ms
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.492 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.502 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.502 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.502 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.512 LabApp] Found kernel ir in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.512 LabApp] Found kernel python2 in c:\users\g30622\desktop\miniconda3\miniconda3\share\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.512 LabApp] Found kernel python3 in C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels
[D 11:22:50.512 LabApp] 200 GET /api/kernelspecs?1510136570472 (127.0.0.1) 30.00ms
```

Comment: There were several issues like that on the GitHub, but now they are all closed. Are you sure you are running the latest version of jupyterlab?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I am also having it after updating all packages.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was solved by changing which browser is used to open Jupyterlab. When I use Internet Explorer (my laptop's default, unfortunately), jupyterlab opens an empty browser tab. Opening in Chrome makes it work perfectly. You can force it to open in Chrome by first running

```
jupyter lab --generate-config
```

then open the config file generated (the generate-config command will give the path to this file). Add the following line to the config file:

```
c.LabApp.browser = r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --app=%s'
```

You don't need to include `--app=%s`, but if you do it will open jupyter lab in its own window, without the url line and extra buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Adding what solved this issue for me, since I couldn't find it anywhere else -

In my case the issue had nothing to do with any browser issues (I tried with incognito and with FF and got the same results).

Not sure what the problem is but the workaround is to uninstall the jupyterlab from conda:
`conda uninstall jupyterlab`
and then install it using pip:
`pip install jupyterlab`

May need to throw in this PATH adjustment afterwards:
`export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`